# No debug while executing VF page with force.com site

Tags: visualforce, force.com, force.com-sites, debugging, debug

The system does not show me the controller debug log of my VF page.

the VF page is viewed with site. and I added a guest user as a monitoring user.

Any Idea?

Comment: Also add your current user as a monitoring user. try this if it help you

Comment: Still can't view my controller debugging!

Comment: Go to Monitoring>Debug log.

Where you would normally put the username, put the name of the Site.

For example: If your site is called MySite, enter MySite as the user name. Shockingly undocumented, but this gives you the debug you're looking for.

Comment: Did you follow above step.

Comment: Yes, it said there's no user with this name

Comment: Has it any relationshipt with RemoteAction annotation?

Comment: Try to Search with the site name. Can you please tell me what is your site name and Which users you add in the debug log. No i don't think because debug of remote actions are also available.

Comment: Searching with the same name there is the Guest User wich I added aleadry as monitoring user

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your VisualForce Debug Log Level Settings?  If its level is set to **ERROR**, then you won't be able to view what's happening until it breaks.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/code_setting_debug_log_levels.htm

Short version: Go to [Your Name]> Developer Console> Click on Debug menu> Change Log Levels.

Once here, change your VisualForce log level to **Fine**.   Now, reset your logs for the users you are tracking and load your page.[image]

Answer (score 1):

When i started working with Force.com Sites i faced this problem many a times.

The page i try to access will say there is an error occurred and when i try to check the debug logs, there won't be an invocation of any of my controller methods.

So if i check the debug logs for the user(either portal user or guest user) i will be getting debug logs which have only the getters and setters for the variables in controller.

If you notice keenly, the last getter or setter would be the last executed code and failed there itself without moving further.

So i start investigating those specific setters and getters and found the reasons.

Hope this helps.